# Is it necessary to re-authenticate with OAuth on every single page?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, tumblr

What I'm trying to do is basically have a system that allows people to post to Tumblr via this website using Tumblr's API. I think it would work something like:

1. Get the user to grant our application permission on Tumblr; get the token and secret from Tumblr.
2. If this user has never authenticated before, store the OAuth token, OAuth secret, and the user those belong to in a database.
3. If the user has authenticated before, check the OAuth token and secret that Tumblr just gave us against the ones already stored in the database to re-authenticate this user.

So, do I need to re-authenticate with OAuth on every single page? Or in other words, I need to contact Tumblr every time the user loads a page to make sure they're still the person they say they are?

Comment: once you get the OAuth Token no, not untill it expires

Comment: So if I've got the token, should I just be checking it against the user's $_SESSION['oauth-token'] on every page load to make sure they're not trying to impersonate someone else then? And then I could just run a check on the responses Tumblr sends me after posting things to make sure the tokens haven't expired.

Comment: once you authenticate then, your site takes over tracking who they are

Comment: I just realized that I have been making much of my PHP code far more complicated than it needs to be. $_SESSION variables are server-side. What a revelation! Thank you for your help Dagon, I just misunderstood some things about how the variables are handled between OAuth and the client and server, so I was needlessly complicating things.